# Grails & Java - Call grails class-method inside java

Tags: java, email, grails

First of all, is this possible?

Why, I am integrating some legacy java code into Grails and would like to use a grails mail plugin. The code sending the email is inside a java class. I don't to rename the file to .groovy since there are several hundred java files.

If this is possible, kindly post a sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. All Grails service/controllers/etc is a Spring beans. And you can configure it to pass mailer bean into any other bean. For example you can create 2 beans:

- *mailerService* - plain groovy/grails service, that sends mail
- *legacyCode* - bean from legacy java code, configured as bean at `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml`. And after that you can use this bean from any other controller, service, etc.

You can put your Java code into `src/java`, or containing jar into `lib`

See http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can call any java code from groovy.  Either put the class in src/java or add a jar containing the code to your classpath.